# Browser back button and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser

I need to restrict, if User uses browser back button and save the page again.
Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

Use cookie or session with short expiration time, so if(cookie/session) then don't save the page again.

Comment: Thanks Quynh.. How do i make cookies or session with short expiration time? Please explain...

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Back functionality using history.forward**

This is another technique to disable the back functionality in any webpage. We can disable the back navigation by adding following code in the webpage. Now the catch here is that you have to add this code in all the pages where you want to avoid user to get back from previous page. For example user follows the navigation page1 -> page2. And you want to stop user from page2 to go back to page1. In this case all following code in page1

```
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
      window.history.forward();
      function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
    <BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

The above code will trigger history.forward event for page1. Thus if user presses Back button on page2, he will be sent to page1. But the history.forward code on page1 pushes the user back to page2. Thus user will not be able to go back from page1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using back button disabling, we can go ahead by adding :disable_with => "Processing" in the save button.

**<%=submit_tag "Save",:class => "buttons", :id => 'save_btn', :disable_with => "Processing" %>**

This will make the save button disable,(even if user refresh the page using F5 or refresh button) if user uses back button of the browser.

*Note: It will not work for Ctrl + F5*

Cheers!